# Would this function be O(n^2log_2(n))?

Tags: big-o, computer-science

So I am given a function like 65536 n<sup>2</sup> + 128 n log<sub>2</sub>n

and the only way that this would be O(n<sup>2</sup> log<sub>2</sub>n) is if

C = 65664, n0 = 2 for all n ≥ 2 since

C1 = 65536 n1 = 2 when 65536 ≤ C1*n<sup>2</sup> and
C2 = 128 n2 = 1 when 128 ≤ C2*n

but the number I've chosen for the constant seems a bit to high, is there a way to check this?

Comment: Which function grows quicker n^2 or nlog_2(n)?

Comment: n^2, but would that be O((n^2)(log_2(n)))? @dbarnes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(65536 n<sup>2</sup> + 128 n log<sub>2</sub>n) is the same as O(n<sup>2</sup> + n log<sub>2</sub>n) since you can ignore multiplicative constants. O(n<sup>2</sup> + n log<sub>2</sub>n) is equal to **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** since n<sup>2</sup> grows faster than n log<sub>2</sub>n.

Also, by the way, the base of logarithms doesn't matter in Big-O analysis. All logarithms grow at the same rate. After all, log<sub>2</sub>n = log n / log 2, and multiplicative constants can be factored out. You can simply say log n instead of log<sub>2</sub>n.

**Caveat:** Technically, it is actually a true statement to say that 65536 n<sup>2</sup> + 128 n log<sub>2</sub>n ∈ O(n<sup>2</sup> log<sub>2</sub>n) because Big-O gives *an* upper bound, but not a strict one. O(n<sup>2</sup>) is a *lower* upper bound, if that makes sense.

That said, you should not have come up with O(n<sup>2</sup> log<sub>2</sub>n). That was merely the result of accidentally turning an addition into a multiplication. As a rule of thumb, if you have multiple things added together inside a Big-O formula, you just have to figure out which one of them grows the fastest and then discard the others.

Comment: Thank you for this. The question is asking whether a list of functions "could" be (n^2logn) and that one just seemed a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

let's simplify the equation here since the constants don't really matter:

n<sup>2</sup> + n log<sub>2</sub>n

since n<sup>2</sup> >  n log<sub>2</sub>n as n approches infinity

the Big-O is O(n<sup>2</sup>) as n<sup>2</sup> is the upper bound.